# I have several activities that I want to string together using tabs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

In order to do this, I think they need to be fragments or something because that is what viewpager requires. I am not really sure how to do this because I have built my app up using activities, not fragments. Is there a simple way to tab between activities so that the tab bar is persistent?

Comment: No, sorry. You will need to migrate to using fragments, then add your tabs.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to adjust your activity code to fragment code.  If you want to use your activity code... well you wouldn't be able to use viewpager but you could make your own view like viewpager.  However, that would be significantly more difficult and less efficient than just using fragments.

Comment: @AnonAnonym Is there any way to just create a simple tab layout that links activities? I don't need the activities to be persistent, just the tab bar.

Comment: I mean anything is possible.  If you absolutely must keep activities then I would try to do some sort of top bar and load a menu with onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsMenuSelected().  I'd use the latter to write intents to move between activities and on start of each activity reload the menu and put in some sort of code to highlight the tab that is selected.  There is no way to keep the bar persistent, when you load a new activity it will destroy the old bar.  You will have to code it so that it redoes the bar so that it looks like it did in the prior activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah was hoping to avoid that because a persistent bar looks way cooler. The old tab layout seems to work with activities and allowed for a persistent toolbar but it's depreciated now. sigh.